# Looking for color changing reaction to track snow layer depth

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solubility, materials, color

I'm trying to find a chemical to mark the position of a snow layer with for detection in future seasons.

**The substance has to be:**
1. Colorless
2. Not water soluble/solid
3. Stable for multiple years
4. Easily detectable in the field

I'm aware of pH tracers, but I am wondering if there are other reactions with one colorless solid/insoluble component that would produce a dramatic color change.

Comment: Have you searched Google Scholar https://scholar.google.com/? When you have a scientific idea in mind, you search the relevant literature and see what others have done in the field.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, unfortunately this research area (wet firn densification) is understudied, largely because of this issue. The method in the literature is either to use naturally deposited sediment layers (usually volcanic ash, problematic for multiple reasons), or water isotopes. It is also unfortunately impractical to remove our cores from the field. Coming up with a material that could more easily facilitate layer tracking would be a huge help both for this and a variety of other research areas in snow science/glaciology.